# android: sending intent via intent

Tags: android

I have one

```
Intent launchIntent = packageManagerForListener.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagesForAdapter[position].name);
```

My question is how can I send this `intent` in an `intent` to another `service` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) with Intent as second parameter. Intent implements Parcalable, so that should work. To get it back you just use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) & cast to Intent.

Comment: I prefer this simple tutorial : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @GhostDerfel yes sure, but question was how to send an Intent object via an Intent) Tutorial doesn't explicitly define that so I defined a sequence of methods to achieve desired result

Comment: Because of that I post the link as a comment to complement your answer